# Get the last item in hash from redis using python

Tags: python, redis

Using redis `hgetall`, gets all items as a dict.

How do i get the last five items in hash?
Would like not to process the entire dict if possible.

```
dt = cxn.hgetall(k)

lt =[[key, dt[key]]for key in sorted(dt.iterkeys()) ]
```

Above does not give me a clean solution, have to process `lt`
again. Using python 2.7

EDIT: `hgetall(k) return {'21': 'fooo', '2': 'bar' },` notice the key is string.

Comment: so you want sort by integer value of the keys?

Comment: yes. thats one way, only pull last five from 'hgetall'....looking something like ....for lrange mylist -6 -1

Comment: see this simple example & let me know if ths is what you want?<http://ideone.com/yJ4GH>

Comment: what's your expected output from my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> dic={'1':100,'2':200,'3':300,'4':400,'5':500,'6':600,'7':700}

>>> print [[str(key), dic[str(key)]]for key in sorted(map(int,dic.iterkeys()))[-5:] ]
[['3', 300], ['4', 400], ['5', 500], ['6', 600], ['7', 700]]
```

Comment: pls: change this ans to same as link.